# Merging two matrix (power balancing)

Tags: matlab

I have two sets of seismic data active and passive in (Frequency-Space) domain. Both with the dimensions (A x B x C)
where A : frequencies, B : receivers and C : Sources.

I would like to merge the active and passive together by summing them for a latter step but I have a problem with the power. The absolute range for the active data ranges from (0 - 250) and for the passive data it ranges from (0-10^-5). which means after merging the passive is negotiable. 
I tried to compensate for that by multiplying the passive with ( max active / max passive ) ratio. 
I am wondering if someone could tip me with some more creative idea here. Maybe an idea for a code that does that.

Comment: Have you thought this through? What exactly is it that you want? What do you want the results to look like? It's really hard to answer without knowing what you want to achieve. Why do you want to merge the results?

Comment: The idea is to have them at same power. if one is extremely small compare to the other there is no point of merging them. The passive data has information in the lower frequency and the active data has data in the higher frequency. By merging both together with the same power I achieve a wider coverage of frequencies. But as it stands when I merge them its like I only have the active data. I hope i made this somehow clearer

Comment: Not sure what you exactly are trying to do, but perhaps plotting the distribution (histogram?) of both variables gives you some creative ideas? Or perhaps you should first process them separately and then combine the result rather than the raw data?